# Optimised call to retrieve indices of the masked elements of a masked array?

Tags: python, arrays

I have a masked array:

```
a = np.arange(7)
a = np.ma.masked_greater(a,4)
```

a then contains

```
masked_array(data = [0 1 2 3 4 -- --],
             mask = [False False False False False  True  True],
       fill_value = 999999)
```

What I'm looking for now is an efficient way to retrieve an array that lists the index of each masked element, i.e.

```
res = [5, 6]
```

without looping through the mask like so:

```
res = []  
for idx, data in enumerate(np.ma.getmaskarray(a)):
    if data:
      res.append(idx)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
>>> a
masked_array(data = [0 1 2 3 4 -- --],
             mask = [False False False False False  True  True],
       fill_value = 999999)
>>> np.where(np.ma.getmaskarray(a))
(array([5, 6]),)
```